# Uploading an image to API url using python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

```
            session = requests.Session()
            url = "...api/auth/login"
            payload = {
                "userName": "user@mail.com",
                "password": "password"
            }
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
            response = session.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
           
            png_uri = DataURI.from_file(image_path)

            files = {
                'file': (
                    os.path.basename(image_path),
                    png_uri,
                    'image/png'
                ),
                'filename': os.path.basename(image_path),
                'upload': '',
            }
            response = session.post(upload_url, files=files)
            print(response.text)
```

As shown in the code above I open the image and convert it to dataURI that I send to the endpoint via a POST request.

The issue is that I'm getting an error:

```
{"error code":400,"message":"Invalid file type"}
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have the API documentation (Swagger\something similar)? If so please share it

Comment: Unfortunately, the API is private and doesn't contain any "body" examples

Answer (score 1):

So Im not sure how the api you are posting to handles files.

but I created a very simple post to webhook.site so you can see the json data you are sending

I think what is going wrong with your post is this part. The Api that receives the data might not be able to parse the 'file' data.

```
files = {
    'file': (
        os.path.basename(image_path),
        png_uri,
        'image/png'
    ),
    'filename': os.path.basename(image_path),
    'upload': '',
}
```

So instead maybe lay it out like this:

```
files = {
    'file': png_uri,
    'type': 'image/png',
    'filename': os.path.basename(image_path),
    'upload': ''
}
```

Here is the the difference in json to an api:
Your post:
[image: Your Image]

My post:
[image: My Image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it was much easier than that.

The API was just badly documented...

```
files = {
                'upload': (
                    os.path.basename(image_path),
                    image_fp,
                    'image/png',
                )
            }
```